# Create many new empty columns in an existing R data frame from a list of column names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an existing R dataframe that is filled out.  I want to enter in new information in a series of new columns.  If I have a list of the column names, is there an easy way to form all these empty columns?

I will then fill out the entries based on outputs of later calculations

MWE

```
animal = c("echidna", "kangaroo", "emu")
age = c(3, 7, 4)
df <- data.frame(animal, age)

newColumns = c("pen", "colour", "sex")
```

I know I can do

```
df$pen = NA
df$colour = NA
df$sex = NA
```

but since I have the list, and it's long - is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: `df[newColumns] <- NA`

Comment: Is there a reason you want to pre-add them? Are you filling them later? Can you not just assign them once you've created them?

Comment: @MrFlick I just find it easier to set up the structure of the df and then fill in the individual cells as I calculate them.  If I create them all in one go I can then just update each individual cell as required.  I don't know if this is a good or bad way to do it, but from an understanding my code perspective it makes things easier for me.